# Pyspark: Trying to Convert a Column to binary using a 'greater than' boolean expression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to create a new column that only holds values for something 'greater than 1'?
There's a column for retweets and I need to make a new column that is binary. 0 for zero retweets, 1 for one retweet or more in pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df.withColumn('greater_than_1', (F.col('retweets').cast('int') >= 1).cast('int'))
```

Comment: i got the column but no values, it's an empty column.

Comment: Then that's because your `retweets` column is empty

Comment: also the columns are strings, do they need to be ints or numerical?

Comment: Oh yes, you can cast them to int. I've edited my answer

Comment: retweets has the values, but it's a string column.

Comment: As a side note, i am about to do some modeling. Should I convert all the other columns into int?

Comment: @TS1000 Of course. You should specify a sensible schema when initialising your dataframe, instead of having them all as strings.

Comment: ok i'lll be asking another question in a moment bc sto-flow is warning me not to post too much here. definitely could use your help

Comment: Ack, it won't let me post. I have a dataframe that has string columns, how do I convert them all to int or numerical columns for modeling in pyspark?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224278/discussion-between-mck-and-ts1000).